# Characters display wrong in JavaScript/PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm having a problem with an SQL database in combination with JavaScript, and it's really awkward.

**HTML on page "configuration.php"**

```
<input id="action_description" type="text"/>
<input id="send" type="button" onClick="addAction()"/>
```

**JavaScript on script.js**

```
function addAction(){
      var action = document.getElementById('action_description').value;
      if (action == ""){
      window.alert("error");
      }
      else {
      xmlhttp.open("GET","doConfig.php?action=2&param1="+action,false);
      xmlhttp.send();
     }
}
```

I do actually the xmlhttp for Microsoft or other, but this is not of interest to the problem.

**PHP on doConfig.php**

```
include('db.php');
mysqli_set_charset($link,'utf8');
$action= $_GET['action'];
switch ($action){
     case '2':
              $text = $_GET['param1'];
              $sql = "INSERT into actions (text) VALUES ('$text')";
              echo $sql;
              mysqli_query($link,$sql);
     break;
}
```

**Database**

Database in XAMPP with phpMyAdmin. Charset UTF8_bin.

The column is named "text" and is format "text (255)".

**Problem:**

Now the problem is, when I use characters from my country (ä ü ö ), the database messes up those. For example the character `Ä` gets displayed as an A and a quarter symbol.

But, when I copy the `echo $sql`, for example `"INSERT into actions (text) VALUES ('ähä?)"` to my phpMyAdmin console into the SQL-Field, then it works perfectly, and the character gets displayed right.

Comment: Save your scripts in UTF-8 encoding and your webcontent like `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` btw why `utf8_bin` and not `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` for example?

Comment: <meta> doesnt work. whats the difference? the database choosed that format, not me.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is right in your database use the header function of php to display utf-8 characters on your page:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: i added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` to doConfig.php, but nothing changes!

Comment: Read my answer... That's not what i posted, you need to add the PHP header from my post.

Comment: Hmm ok. And what happens if you add the header and use: **echo utf8_encode($sql);** ??